# How to create original Data Tables (AspNetRoles/AspNetUsers/AspNetUserRoles/AspNEtUserLogins..) with Oracle DB in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-5, asp.net-web-api2

I do have a serious problem , I can automate to create data tables ( included AspNetRoles/AspNetUsers/AspNetUserRoles/AspNEtUserLogins etc..) in Visual Studio 2015 with MSSQL/MySQL but how can I use Oracle to do the same thing, please do me a favor to give me solutions or any slight club.

Answer (score 1):

From a different piece of software I have been working with in the past I had this same issue when I was lacking the Oracle ODBC drivers on the machine trying to connect to this database.

Could this maybe be the same problem you have here? In that case you would need to install the Orable ODBC connectors and then recreate the tables.

Comment: in fact I have installed ODAC and Visual Studio 2015 [URL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html), so that I have tried this issue may ways ,but unfortunately it's working for me . so that hopefully you have any slight clue to help me , thanks again .